# Label to blink/turn off when the button is pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Sorry for the elementary question.

I want to create a UI that makes the Label blink/turn off when a button is pressed in a WPF application.

I was able to make the Label blink when the screen started, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to notify the Label when the button is pressed.

1.I created the XAML for blinking Label as BlinkingLabel.xaml.

I changed the build action of this file to resource.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Storyboard x:Key="FlashStory">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True">
        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="1" />
        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="0" />
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>


<Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="LabelFlash">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Label.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FlashStory}" />
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

2.I specified that I can refer to BlinkingLabel.xaml created in App.xaml.

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp2.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="BlinkingLabel.xaml" />
</Application.Resources>
```

3.I wrote MainWindow.xaml like this.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>



        <Label x:Name="lblMessage"
               Content="connecting"
               Grid.Column="1"
               Foreground="White"
               FontSize="22" 
               Background="LightBlue"
               HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
               VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
               Height="40"
               Style="{StaticResource LabelFlash}" />

        <Button Click="ConnectStart"
                Content="Start"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Height="40">
        </Button>

        <Button Click="ConnectStop"
                Content="Stop"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.Row="2"
                Height="40">
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Since Label.Loaded is specified in BlinkingLabel.xaml, I found that blinking starts when the screen starts up.

However, I want this part to blink when the button is pressed, but I'm worried because I don't know how to specify an event other than label (such as button.Click).

How can I trigger the state of another element?

Sorry for my poor English.

Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement a blinking label, I created a class that defines a blinking label.

①Create a class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

namespace BlinkTest
{
internal class BlinkLabel : Label
{
    private Storyboard _storyboard;

    public BlinkLabel()
    {
        _storyboard = new Storyboard
        {
            RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever,
        };


        var animation = new DoubleAnimation
        {
            From = 1.0,
            To = 0.0,
            AutoReverse = true,
            Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)),
        };

        _storyboard.Children.Add(animation);

        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, this);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(OpacityProperty));
    }


    public void Start()
    {
        _storyboard.Begin();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _storyboard.Stop();
    }
  }
}
```

②Place label in XAML. In this example, a start button is also placed.

```
<Window x:Class="BlinkTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BlinkTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <local:BlinkLabel x:Name="BlinkLabel"
                      FontSize="24"
                      FontWeight="Bold"
                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                      Height="70"
                      Grid.Column="0"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                      Grid.Row="1"/>

    <Button Content="Start"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Height="50"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Click="StartButton_Click"/>

    <Button Content="Stop"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Height="50"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Click="StopButton_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

③When the button is clicked, Start and Stop defined in ① are called to start and stop blinking.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace BlinkTest
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BlinkLabel.Content = "Start";
        BlinkLabel.Foreground = Brushes.White;
        BlinkLabel.Background = Brushes.PaleVioletRed;
        BlinkLabel.Start();
    }

    private void StopButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BlinkLabel.Content = "Stop";
        BlinkLabel.Foreground = Brushes.White;
        BlinkLabel.Background = Brushes.DimGray;
        BlinkLabel.Stop();
    }
 }
}
```

④Press the button to confirm blinking.
[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqXRx.png)

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to only apply the blinking style to the label in your button's click handler, so before that it would behave as a normal label. This is typically the way things are done in CSS, adding classes to change animations.

A more robust way is to implement a label subclass that has a `IsBlinking` property, and use that as a conditional in your style to only run the animation when it's on. Then in your button click handler you simply set the property to true and watch the magic happen.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.
Thanks for the advice.

What you mentioned as an easy way to do this, for example, using Timer.Tick in the button click handler to make it blink?

Comment: No, you already wrote the animation style to make it blink, my suggestion is to only attach it to the button in response to the click event rather than at creation like you did.

Comment: I'm sorry it took so long.

I tried various things based on the advice to implement a subclass.

Perhaps, it may be different from what Blindy imagined, but the desired operation was achieved.

XAML is still difficult for me, and implementing a subclass was easier to imagine.

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could stop and start a `Storyboard` that is stared using a `<BeginStoryboard>` XAML element:

```
private void ConnectStop(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    lblMessage.BeginAnimation(Label.OpacityProperty, null);
}

private void ConnectStart(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ConnectStop(sender, e);
    Storyboard sb = this.FindResource("FlashStory") as Storyboard;
    if (sb != null)
    {
        lblMessage.BeginStoryboard(sb);
    }
}
```